# Alarm Manager is crashing

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am using following code,

```
public class Live extends ActionBarActivity {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_live);

        Long time = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+10*1000;

        Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intentAlarm, 0);

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time, alarmIntent);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),1000 * 10, alarmIntent);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Manager calling....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

In in My manifest file, I have included following line also
`<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"/>`

And my AlarmReceiver Class is simply shows Toast

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
                 Toast.makeText(context,"Alarm ringing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

So when I launch Application, it gives me null pointer exception Log cat is

```
    05-07 14:27:49.192: E/AndroidRuntime(17793): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-07 14:27:49.192: E/AndroidRuntime(17793): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.livestream/com.example.livestream.Live}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-07 14:27:49.192: E/AndroidRuntime(17793):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
05-07 14:27:49.192: E/AndroidRuntime(17793):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
05-07 14:27:49.192: E/AndroidRuntime(17793):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
05-07 14:27:49.192: E/AndroidRuntime(17793):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
05-07 14:27:49.192: E/AndroidRuntime(17793):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-07 14:27:49.192: E/AndroidRuntime(17793):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-07 14:27:49.192: E/AndroidRuntime(17793):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
05-07 14:27:49.192: E/AndroidRuntime(17793):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-07 14:27:49.192: E/AndroidRuntime(17793):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-07 14:27:49.192: E/AndroidRuntime(17793):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
05-07 14:27:49.192: E/AndroidRuntime(17793):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
05-07 14:27:49.192: E/AndroidRuntime(17793):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-07 14:27:49.192: E/AndroidRuntime(17793): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-07 14:27:49.192: E/AndroidRuntime(17793):    at com.example.livestream.Live.onCreate(Live.java:63)
05-07 14:27:49.192: E/AndroidRuntime(17793):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5203)
05-07 14:27:49.192: E/AndroidRuntime(17793):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
05-07 14:27:49.192: E/AndroidRuntime(17793):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2078)
05-07 14:27:49.192: E/AndroidRuntime(17793):    ... 11 more
```

Can you tell me where am I going wrong??

Comment: what comes on `Line 63 of Live.java`? you have a crash over there!

Comment: Is         alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),1000 * 10, alarmIntent); 63 line?

check calendar for null

Comment: @Suvitruf: Thnx for your help... I didn't initialized calender...

Answer (score 0):

You should try to remove the `set` method

```
 alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time, alarmIntent);
```

and use only `setRepeating` (if you want to repeat the service, otherwise remove setRepeating)

After this you must create a class which extends `IntentService` and insert the method `onHandleIntent`

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    ..code here.. (toast example)
}
```

after that, on Receiver class, rewrite the `onReceiver` method and insert an intent that calls your service

```
Intent i = new Intent(context,IntentService);
context.startService(i);
```

in the last step, add Service information in the Manifest (like the receiver)

```
<service android:name=".name of your class"
    android:exported="true" />  <-I write also this
```